# In Schrödinger equation, can we get $\Psi$ if we know $\varphi(n)$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, wavefunction

Let $A$ be a mechanical quantity and we know its eigenfunction $\varphi(n)$. Can we get its wave function $\Psi$, if we measure $A$ for many (maybe infinite) times at the same time?

Comment: You need lots of clarification. If I assume you mean $A$ is an observable with functions $A\phi=n\phi$. What does "it's wave function" mean? The wave function is usually a solution to a wave equation - which I guess maybe you mean Schroedinger. I guess you are asking if $\phi$ can be simultaneously a solution to a wave equation and an eigenfunction of an operator $A$? Sure - if your schroedinger equation is $\hat{H}\phi=E_n\phi$.

Comment: In equation HΦ=EΦ, Φ is a function of x, we measure the position and get Φ0(x).By using Fourier transform and adding exp(-iEt/(h/2π）), we get Ψ, is it right? But what if we measure the other quantity(momentum P, for example) and get Φ0(P) at first?

Comment: @levitopher What you say is right only if $[A,H]=0$.

Comment: @wizard423 if you speak Spanish please tell me your question in Spanish and I'll edit your question so we can understand it.

Comment: I think he means that upon measurement a state $\Psi$ becomes an eigenstate $\phi_n$ of the associated operator, $A$, with some probability $a_n^2$. By multiple, simultaneous measurements, could we determine all the coefficients $a_n$ and thus the original state $\Psi$?

Comment: By writing $\Psi = \Sigma a_n \phi_n$.  Short answer is no - no such simultaneous measurements are possible, and if they were, wouldn't recover phases in this example. But poses a more philosophical question about reality of the wave function prior to measurement etc

Comment: @wizard423: When you ask questions in the future, keep in mind that $\phi$ and $\Psi$ are just symbols until you tell us that one is a function of position and one of momentum (if that's indeed what you mean). In particular, writing "eigenfunction $phi(n)$" suggests $\phi$ is a function of something (which maybe an integer), but suggests it is not a function of position.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm right, you're talking about the Fourier transform that we use to get the wave function as a function of x at time t, and you're question is that what if we happened to measure the wave function as a function of p (momentum) at time t=0, then how do we get $\phi (p, t)$?
The key is in the representation you're using. If you write the Hamiltonian in position space, then in the equation $H \psi(x) = E \psi(x)$, the wave function is going to be a function of position. Now if you want $\phi (k)$ or $\phi (p)$ you're going to have to write the Hamiltonian in the momentum space. then you will have $H \phi (k) = E \phi (k)$.

Then : $$\displaystyle \phi(k, 0) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\psi(x)e^{-ikx}dx$$
 and so we have: $$\displaystyle \psi(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\phi(k, 0)e^{ikx}dk$$ 
and finally : $$\displaystyle \phi (k, t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\psi(x)e^{-i(kx+\frac{\hbar k^2t}{2m})}dx$$.

Like I said, the rep. is important. $H|\psi>$ can be written as:

$<x|H|\psi> = H(\text{in position space})\times <x|\psi> = H\psi(x)$, or you can write for p (or k) :  $<p|H|\psi> = H(\text{in momentum space})\times <p|\psi> = H\psi(p)$.